# Notepad++: What is the "opposite" format of JSFormat?

Tags: json, notepad++

I'm looking for the "opposite" Format of JSFormat from the JSTools. Here an example:

JSON code example:

```
title = Automatic at 07.02.17 & appId = ID_1 & data = {
    "base": "+:background1,background2",
    "content": [{
            "appTitle": "Soil",
            "service": {
                "serviceType": "AG",
                "Url": "http://test.de/xxx"
            },
            "opacity": "1"]
        }
    ],
    "center": "4544320.372869264,5469450.086030475,31468"
}
& context = PARAMETERS
```

and I Need to convert the Format to the following format:

```
title=Automatic at 07.02.17 &appId=ID_1&data={"base":"+:background1,background2","content":[{"appTitle":"Soil","service":{"serviceType":"AG","Url":"http://test.de/xxx"},"opacity":"1"]}],"center":"4544320.372869264,5469450.086030475,31468"}&context=PARAMETERS
```

which is a decoded URL (with MIME Tools) from this html POST:

```
title%3DAutomatic%20at%2007.02.17%20%26appId%3DID_1%26data%3D%7B%22base%22%3A%22+%3Abackground1,background2%22,%22content%22%3A%5B%7B%22appTitle%22%3A%22Soil%22,%22service%22%3A%7B%22serviceType%22%3A%22AG%22,%22Url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ftest.de%2Fxxx%22%7D,%22opacity%22%3A%221%22%5D%7D%5D,%22center%22%3A%224544320.372869264,5469450.086030475,31468%22%7D%26context%3DPARAMETERS%0D%0A
```

which I have to come back after doing changes in the JSON code. From the second to the third Format I can use URL encode (MIME Tools), but what about the reformating from the first to the second Format.

**My question:** Do you have ideas how to turn the first (JSON) Format into the second (decoded URL) in Notepad++? Something like the "opposite" of JSFormat?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you basically need to put your JSON on a single line removing new lines and spaces.

This should be achieved with these steps:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace occurrences of more than one space with empty string using this regex: `[ ]{2,}` (remember to select "*Regular expression*" radiobutton). If this is not exactly what you want you can adjust the regular expression to achieve desired output
2. select all your JSON <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
3. put everything on a single line with join <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

You can also record a macro to automate this process and run it with a keyboard shortcut.